# switch python version on uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, mod-wsgi, uwsgi

I am running a django app with nginx and uwsgi. It was was working ok but suddenly I do not know what  I changed that the app stop working.

The problem resides in that python version from uWsgi is 2.4.3 which is the default version in Linux CentOs and I have installed django, webpy and other python distributions in version 2.7.3 (will upgrade sooner)

I also tried creating a symbolic link from python 2.7 path to just "python" in usr/bin
and did not work.

How can I make uWsgi use python2.7.3(/usr/local/bin/) instead of 2.4.3?

Django ini:

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
master = true
processes = 4
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djtest.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
```

When I initialize

```
./uwsgi --ini django.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from django.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.3 (64bit) on [Sat Nov 24 00:27:55 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52) on 23 November 2012 22:37:39
os: Linux-2.6.18-194.17.4.el5xen #1 SMP Mon Oct 25 16:36:31 EDT 2010
nodename: v238545.hostingator.net
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root
detected binary path: /opt/uwsgi/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 32832
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 5841)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:59395 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.4.3 (#1, Jun 18 2012, 08:55:23)  [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1cc1130
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
mapped 72352 bytes (70 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /usr/local/bin/ to pythonpath.
added /home/indaxone/serv/ to pythonpath.
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 5840, cores: 1)
```

Comment: Very helpful read >> https://serverfault.com/a/916780/345808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before doing the "make" during the uwsgi installation I did the following:

```
python2.7 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```