# uWSGI runs wrong version of Python

Tags: python, django, version, pip, uwsgi

My django/uwsgi/python crashes with a segmentation fault because uWSGI is apparently loading a different version of Python.

I just installed uWSGI using pip.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537373/swtich-python-version-on-uwsgi) addresses a solution that involves compiling from source, but I'd like to avoid that.

```
mihai$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Segmentation fault: 11

mihai$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Any suggestions?

I was hoping for some --flag that can tell uWSGI what version of python to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly if the python it is compiled against is the wrong one you have to recompile it.
Since it is directly linked to the Python it was built for if you are using a different one the symbols won't match.

In the comments you mention you used pip but are not getting the right Python version. Perhaps you are using the wrong pip? For instance on Ubuntu you have Python 2.7 and 3.3. There is a pip-2.7 and a pip-3.3. If you are using virtualenv make sure you are installing with pip from the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  What do you mean by recompile - build from scratch instead of pip?

I tried reinstalling with pip with no luck - is there another workaround such as this?  Maybe if I remove the offending python version and then re-install uwsgi with pip?

Comment: Explain how you have multiple Python versions. That will help figure out the right solution.

Comment: Well, I just have one now, the one that came with OSX Mavericks.

I removed the one I had installed with homebrew, which is also the one that caused the crash.  I uninstalled and reinstalled uwsgi - same problem.

I now only have one version of python, but uwsgi seems to still be hooked on to a different one.

And by version I don't mean numbers, they were both 2.7.6.  But the Homebrew one was compiled with an Apple compiler, and the default OSX one is compiled with GCC:

    Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Comment: Where did pip come from? Did you use homebrew for that too? If so you should remove it too. Install pip using the system python and then all should be well. But at some point the uwsgi needs to be compiled and it needs to find the Python headers and libraries for the version of Python you are using which means it should be the same python that installed pip.

Comment: To be clear, there is nothing wrong with using Homebrew to install an alternate Python version. However, when you do you have to be very careful to use the components matching the Python version you want to use. This means /usr/local/bin/pip should be the home brew pip and the system's pip should be somewhere else. _OR_ you invoke pip as /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pip .... for the system Python and /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pip .... to get the homebrew version.

Comment: Ah!  That's starting to make sense.  So I actually have three versions of pip on my system...  I'll make sure I use the right one.
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip
(and why can't I get code intents to work in the comments??)

Comment: Use backticks like this \`foo\`.

Comment: Can I assume that /usr/local/bin/pip goes with /usr/local/bin/python?

Comment: Probably safe yeah. You can use the `md5` command to see if it matches either of the ones you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

One non-obvious thing which can cause this problem: you previously installed uwsgi using a different python environment and the resulting compiled uwsgi wheel got saved in your pip wheel cache. Then when you installed uwsgi in your current python environment, pip simply grabbed the cached wheel instead of actually rebuilding uwsgi for your current python version.

Watch the output closely to see if pip used a cached wheel. If so, you can either delete the cached wheel and reinstall uwsgi or reinstall using a command-line arg to disable the cache:

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
pip install --no-cache-dir uwsgi
```