# uWSGI flask.ini uses global Python or virtualevn Python?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

This following codes are inside a uWSGI configuration file called `flask1.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/flask1.sock
chmod-socket = 777
evn = PRODUCTION=TRUE
module = indy
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
logto = /var/indylog
```

The production server is set up on `ubuntu 14.04` using `uWSGI` and `nginx` for `Flask` application.

I wrote a new module that uses `Python 2.7` and it runs without any error on my local `ubuntu 14.04` virtualenv (Flask development server) and the same `nginx` and `uWSGI` set up as the production environment. However, when I deployed the same code live on production server, it gives a bunch of `syntax errors`, I am trying to figure out why this is the case.

I run `python --version` on my local desktop and production server, they are both `Python 2.7.6`.

My questions: with the above uWSGI configuration on production server, which `Python` is being used? The machine `Python` or `virtualenv Python`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537373/swtich-python-version-on-uwsgi

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, neither. uwsgi does not actually run the Python binary, it uses libpython directly. It just follows your system's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find the corresponding libpython library and this is normally not affected by virtualenv.

What *is* affected by virtualenv, however, is the location from which uwsgi will load your packages. You will still need to add a line in your `uwsgi.ini` to specify the path your virtualenv like this:

```
virtualenv = /path/to/your/virtualenv
```

If you wish to configure uwsgi to use different versions of libpython, you will need to build the corresponding plugin for each version and specify it in `uwsgi.ini`. You can find more information about this [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary)

Comment: How do I find out which version of libpython is uwsgi using? Both my local machine and production server are `ubuntu 14.04`, shouldn't they have the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by default?

Comment: AFAIK uwsgi currently uses the 2.7 plugin by default on Ubuntu. If you really want to find out which libpython is open you could run something like `lsof -p <uwsgi_worker_pid>` on your production server. But since you're running Ubuntu 14.04, I think in your case you can just run `sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3` which seems to install and set python3 as the default plugin.

Comment: Forgot to mention: on your development server, you're most likely not using uwsgi but django's `runserver` which runs like a normal Python script, honoring your virtualenv, etc. This is the reason it picks up the correct Python version.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to create Python 3 environment for your source code:
`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 path_to_your_project/env`

And install packets required:

```
cd path_to_your_project
source env/bin/activate
# you can use pip to install packets required, e.g:
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Finally, add virtualenv to your uwsgi.ini file:

```
virtualenv = path_to_your_project/env
```

Answer (score 1):

Install uwsgi in the virtualenv to use whichever Python version the env is configured with.  `/path/to/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /path/to/flask.ini`.  Instead of global `uwsgi path/to/your/flask.ini`, which would use the Python version that the system installed.